# How to convert Object's property values in to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, java-8

Say if I have, a list of objects like:-

```
[id = 1, age = 34, name = "abc"]
[id = 2, age = 34, name = "xyz"]
[id = 3, age = 34, name = "mno"]
```

then I need to convert them to :-

```
[1], [34], [abc],
[2], [34], [xyz],
[3], [34], [mno]
```

Comment: What type do you invision your array to be of? `String`?

Comment: Will the objects always be of a particular known type?  Or will the object types not always be known in advance?

Comment: what kind of array expected? is it [1, 34, "abc", 2, 34, "xyz", 3, 34, "mno"] ?

Comment: Please describe the object and array notation you are using. If you are e.g. referring to JSON, please use JSON syntax.

Comment: Object type is not known always.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use streams with [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) methods:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(1, 50, "John");
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(2, 30, "Michał");
    List<MyClass> list = Arrays.asList(obj, obj2);
    List<Object> all = list.stream()
            .map(o -> Arrays.asList(o.getId(), o.getAge(), o.getName()))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    all.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
}
```

```java
public static class MyClass {
    private final int id;
    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    public MyClass(int id, int age, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each *Object* to an array of its fields `Object[]` as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Person> people = List.of(
            new Person(1, 34, "abc"),
            new Person(2, 34, "xyz"),
            new Person(3, 34, "mno"));

    Object[][] arr = people.stream()
            .map(person -> new Object[]{
                    person.getId(), person.getAge(), person.getName()
            }).toArray(Object[][]::new);

    // output
    Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    //[1, 34, abc]
    //[2, 34, xyz]
    //[3, 34, mno]
}
```

```java
static class Person {
    int id;
    int age;
    String name;

    public Person(int id, int age, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have class Person:

```java
package stack.overflow.atest;

public class Person {
    int id;
    int age;
    String name;

    public Person(int id, int age, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

As of Java 8 you can do something like this:

```java
List<Object> result = Stream
        .of(new Person(1, 23, "aaa"), new Person(2, 34, "bbb"))
        .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.id, p.age, p.name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

this produces:

```
result: [1, 23, aaa, 2, 34, bbb]
```